# Сделать плавное выдвигающееся меню

Tags: javascript, html

```js
var lastOpen;

function collapsElement(id) {
  if (document.getElementById(id).style.display != "none") {
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';
  } else {
    if (lastOpen !== undefined) {
      lastOpen.style.display = 'none';
    }
    lastOpen = document.getElementById(id);
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = '';
  }
}
```

```html
<div><a class="open-content" href="javascript:collapsElement('opencontent')" title="" rel="nofollow">Анкор ссылки</a>
  <div id="opencontent" style="display: none">
    <p>Ваш открывающийся материал</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Надо добавить `transition`, но тут большое `НО`, `display: none"`  `transition-ну` неподвластен

Comment: как это можн исправить ?

Comment: Я бы вообще все удалил... И с нуля написал

Comment: У тебя ссылка, для чего она? Почему ты используешь ссылку для открытия меню?

Comment: выпадающий текст, [ссылка](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MVrEPp)

Comment: Она куда-то ведет?

Comment: да, должен появляться текст, исправил посмотри по той же ссылке

Comment: Уже посмотрел, у тя просто появляется меню, а ссылку надо использовать, если нужен переход куда-то...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно сделать через `transition`, будет вот так:

```js
const openMenu = document.querySelector('.open-button');

openMenu.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  openMenu.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle('open-content--show')
});
```

```css
.open-content {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 1s ease max-height
}

.open-content--show {
  max-height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a class="open-button" href="" title="" rel="nofollow">Анкор ссылки</a>
  <div id="opencontent" class="open-content">
    <p>Ваш открывающийся материал</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

За лучшее старайтесь максимально все сделать через `CSS`, то есть либо вообще без взаимодействия `Javascript`, либо с минимальным. Ваш пример можно сделать вообще без `Javascript`, а на чистом `CSS` через `input type checkbox`. Но здесь я показал, основываясь на Ваш код.

Если нужен старый стандарт `ES5`, тогда `Javascript code` будет вот таким

```
'use strict';

var openMenu = document.querySelector('.open-button');

openMenu.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  openMenu.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle('open-content--show');
});
```

UPDATE: Вариант на чистом `CSS`

```css
label {
    cursor: pointer;
}

label ~ .appear { 
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: 1s ease max-height;
}

input {
    display: none;
}
input:checked ~ .appear {
    max-height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<label for="the-checkbox">Раскрыть</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="the-checkbox" /> 
<div class="appear">Некоторый нужный текст</div>
```

UPDATE 2: Если не нужна анимация, а нужно на чистом html, то вообще вот так. Это вам не подходит. Но пусть будет для других.

```html
<details>
<summary>Раскрыть</summary>
Некоторый текст
</details>
```

Comment: спасибо сделаю через css.

Comment: @easy отметьте вариант правильным, если он вам подходит. Чтобы остальные сразу видели решение, кто будет искать подобный вопрос.

Answer (score 2):

Не зная, что именно тебе надо,  пример абстрактный.  Вместо `display = 'none'`
используй добавление и удаление классов, и далее можно в `css` стилями добываться тех или иных эффектов...  А ссылки для подобных действий, не стоит использовать

```js
const openButton = document.querySelector('#open-button');
const opencontent = document.querySelector('#opencontent');
openButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  openButton.classList.toggle('show');
  opencontent.classList.toggle('open');
});
```

```css
#open-button {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 20px;
  background: red;
  transition: height .5s .3s;
}

#open-button.show {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  transition: height .5s;
}

#opencontent {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: background .1s, opacity .5s .3s;
  background: red;
}

#opencontent.open {
  opacity: 1;
  background: white;
  transition: background .6s .1s, opacity .5s;
}
```

```html
<div id="open-button">Анкор ссылки
  <div id="opencontent" class="open-content">
    <p>Ваш открывающийся материал</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо, понял в чем косяк, буду делать